# Is it possible to send Pseudo-APDU commands while card is not present?

Tags: java, smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader, pcsc

I am using the `javax.smartcardio` package for developing smart card related applications. I want to send Pseudo ADPU commands to set my reader's LED / LCD status.

I found that the only method to send APDU commands to reader/card is `CardChannel::transmit`, but it must be run on card present .

Is it possible to send Pseudo-APDU commands while card is not present in the reader? what about the APDU commands? (Using Java)

Comment: ...I read that as "Smart Cardio". I'm smart, I promise! Also, what does ADPU stand for? I've never seen it before.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: It is better to read it as SmartCardInOut ;) . APDU or Application Data Protocol Unit is a protocol to send commands to smart cards and receive response from them. Simply it is a queue of hexadecimal numbers. minimum length of this commands is 4 bytes (command header) and minimum length of card's answer is 2 bytes (Status Words)

Comment: Take a look at the following thread in oracle community, it seems that it is the same problem that you have : https://community.oracle.com/thread/2193998

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution from sample of card-emul in `SDK for PC/SC` in http://www.springcard.com. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.smartcardio.CardException;
import javax.smartcardio.CardTerminal;
import javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory;

public class TestPcsc {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws CardException {

        TerminalFactory tf = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
        List< CardTerminal > terminals = tf.terminals().list();
        CardTerminal cardTerminal = (CardTerminal) terminals.get( 0 );

        byte[] command = { (byte) 0xE0, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x29, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x00 };
        cardTerminal.connect( "DIRECT" ).transmitControlCommand( CONTROL_CODE(), command );

    }

    public static int CONTROL_CODE() {

        String osName = System.getProperty( "os.name" ).toLowerCase();
        if ( osName.indexOf( "windows" ) > -1 ) {
            /* Value used by both MS' CCID driver and SpringCard's CCID driver */
            return (0x31 << 16 | 3500 << 2);
        }
        else {
            /* Value used by PCSC-Lite */
            return 0x42000000 + 1;
        }

    }

}
```

I think the points are:

1. Using `DIRECT` protocol to get the 'card'
2. Using `Card::transmitControlCommand` method with the code got from CONTROL_CODE function (copied from the sample code, not sure what the theory is >_<)

Answer (score 1):

I think the following method needs a card present in the reader also,  but just for your information I posted it here to say that we there is another method for terminal controlling commands:

Quoted from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/Card.html#transmitControlCommand-int-byte:A-):

> **transmitControlCommand:**
>
> *public abstract byte[] transmitControlCommand(int controlCode,byte[] command) throws CardException*
>
> Transmits a control command to the terminal device. This
> can be used to, for example, control terminal functions like a
> built-in PIN pad or biometrics.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> controlCode - the control code of the command
>
> command -
> the command data
>
> **Throws:**
>
> SecurityException - if a SecurityManager exists and the caller does not have the required permission
>
> NullPointerException - if command is null
>
> CardException - if the card operation failed
>
> IllegalStateException - if this card object has been disposed of via the disconnect() method